# Disconnecting issue in multipleer connectivity

Tags: ios, iphone, file-transfer, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

We are able to make connection from host device to multiple slave devices.
but firstly devices will connected while sharing data they will automatically disconnected .
we already used all delegate methods.

```
- (void) session:(MCSession*)session didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray*)certificate fromPeer:(MCPeerID*)peerID certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler
{
    if (certificateHandler != nil) { certificateHandler(YES); }
}
```

Any help really appreciated ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reword the question?

Comment: Hi mark , Actually we are using multipeer connection to send songs from one device to multiple devices using bluetooth so we are able to make connection between multiple device but connection is not as smooth as we want .very firstly we can create connection ,send data and songs also but as soon as song is going to transfer devices become disconnected .So is there any solution for it .

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to send the songs? Which api your using is important.

Comment: its not based on api ,its based on multipeer connection and songs are transferring via bluetooth ,it also have some own delegate methods.

Comment: By api, I'm referring to which multipeer data transfer method you're using. There is one to transfer NSData, and one to transfer files.